# Load result of query in select html with Java on form Load

Tags: javascript, java, html

i want to load all the name of users of sql query `SELECT name from Users` in html select tag on formload.. the problem is that I have to build html page in java and i don't know how I can make it happen.. i don't know javascript, help me! 
I can't use php because I'm making a program with web services

```html
<html>
<body class="text-center">
<form class="form-signin">
 <select class="form-control" name="users">
 </select>
 <br>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Inserisci</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; 2018-2019</p>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an old solution of creating JSP, where you can integrate HTML with java code snippets. create an internal classes which call data access objects and make a call to these class methods in the jsp. Use HTML CSS to make a user friendly view.
Another way is to use [facelets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX) which will go really well with MVC structure.
In the standard Java EE API, the only alternative to JSP is [Facelets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX). As far now  JSF is the only MVC framework which natively supports [Facelets](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets.htm#GIEPX).